# System of coupled differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system of three linear differential equations that I need to solve numerically using finite diferences:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{dn_0}{dt} &= -n_0(t)W_{01}(t) + n_1(t)K_{10}\\
\frac{dn_1}{dt} &= -n_1(t)W_{12}(t) - n_1(t)K_{10} + n_2(t)K_{21} + n_0(t)W_{01}(t)\\
\frac{dn_2}{dt} &= n_1(t)W_{12}(t) - n_2(t)K_{21}
\end{aligned}$$

where the boundary conditions are

$$ n_0(0)=1 $$
$$ n_0(N)=0 $$
$$ n_1(0)=0 $$
$$ n_1(N)=1 $$
$$ n_2(0)=0 $$
$$ n_2(N)=0 $$

The three equations are restricted by $n_0 + n_1 + n_2 =1$, I tried to replace and write the equations, in an attempt to

$$\frac{dn_0}{dt} + \frac{dn_1}{dt} +\frac{dn_2}{dt} = 0$$

Since I can not use the finite difference method for coupled equations,thinking that as a solution the values of the derivatives should be equal to zero, so I could just rewrite one of the equations by isolating the variables, but I'm not sure about that. Does anyone know a way or some technique that I can decouple the 3 equations?

Comment: Since the equations are linear, have you considered trying to solve them analytically?

Comment: Why can't you use finite difference for that system? It looks like $W's$ are variables as well, what are they?

Comment: $W=A{e^{-(t-t0)^2}}$  I tried solving with finite differences by solving each equation at a time, but failed to eliminate the coupled terms as you did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is a linear time-variant system. We can write it in matrix form as

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}n_0 \\ n_1\\ n_2 \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-W_{01}(t) & K_{10} & 0\\
W_{01}(t) & -K_{10}-W_{12}(t)&K_{12}\\
0 & W_{12}(t) & -K_{21}\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}n_0 \\ n_1\\ n_2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then we have $n_0=1-n_1-n_2$. This invariant allows us to remove the line of the equation. Because if we know $n_1$ and $n_2$ we can simply calculate $n_0$. If we substitute this invariant into the second and third line we obtain.

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix} n_1\\ n_2 \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
-K_{10}-W_{12}(t)-W_{01}(t) &K_{12}-W_{01}(t)\\
W_{12}(t) & -K_{21}\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} n_1\\ n_2 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}W_{01}(t)\\0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Can you supply more information on $W_{12}(t)$ and the other terms? In general, it will be problematic to help you to decouple both equations. But you should be able to solve this coupled system without any problems with numerical solvers for differential equations.

Comment: $W12=A{e^{-(t-t0)^2}}$ and $W10=B{e^{-(t-t0)^2}}$. k10, k12 and A and B are constants.

I did not quite understand what you did to remove n0. What exactly did you do?

Comment: And what is the goal that you want to achieve? Just obtain numerical solutions? Or do you want to carry out a stability analysis of the system?

Comment: Yeah, I want to check how n0, n1 and n2 behave in the system over time. I would need the numerical solution to do other types of simulation.

I tried solving with finite differences by solving each equation at a time, but failed to eliminate the coupled terms as you did

Comment: You should be able to solve this differential equation by using Euler forward. As long as your step size is small enough and the simulation time is not too long you should get reasonable results. Why do you want to use finite difference?

Comment: is the method that I am most familiar with. But I think it will be more difficult with him. Thank you anyway